# react native firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In react native with firebase I get a chat app code. It used a button to show my registered friends, but I want to check when this button click user is logged in or not.

This is the button code in render function

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerl}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="red" />
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Friendlist")}
          >
            SHOW FRIEND LIST
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>       
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I want to add this firebase authentication code in to Show Friend List text press.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('user logged')
      }
   });
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below. Add a flag to check whether the user logged in or not

```
    state = {
  isUserLogged: false
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        isUserLogged: true
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isUserLogged: false
      })
    }
  });
}

render() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.containerl}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="red" />
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={() => {
            if (this.state.isUserLogged) {
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Friendlist")
            } else {
              console.log('user not logged')
            }
          }
          }
        >
          SHOW FRIEND LIST
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show whether a user is logged in or not, you'll need to attach a variable to the user state. So, your authentication code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log('user logged')
  }
 });
```

essentially, will put this method in either the `constructor()` or the `componentDidMount()` method.

From there, you'll need to set the state, like -

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ userLoggedIn: true });
    console.log('user logged')
  }
 });
```

and in your `render()` you can attach conditions to `this.state.userLoggedIn` on your `onPress()` method accordingly.

If you need to send the logged in state to your `<Friendlist/>` component, you'll be required to do  -

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Friendlist", {userLoggedIn: this.state.userLoggedIn})
```

and in your `<Friendlist/>` component you can fetch it from `this.props.navigation.state.params.userLoggedIn`